# General Query about Placement of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am building a demo app with 3 screens. One screen captures barcode from the camera. The second screen displays information about the barcodes. The third screen is just the home screen used to redirect to the two screens.

After I scan the barcodes, I have to make an online query to find information about the barcodes, such as name of the item, manufacturer etc.

For which screen should I connect this functionality to. Should I put the code in the script for the scanning HTML page or the one which displays it?

Is there an option where it happens in the background when none of the two pages are open.

EDIT: I can't attach it to the the home screen page because the user can redirect from one to the other without the home screen as well :(

Comment: Why would you not put it on the page that scans the barcode?

Comment: Because what if the values or information get updated after the user closes that screen @Keegan Teetaert.

Comment: You could save your data in your local storage so it is persistent throughout all pages.